# SpringFramework jsp set restricted urls JAVA

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have copied an example of a page that i am using. If the current user is admin, he can see and use full menu but if the user is regular he can see cutted version of the menu. The problem is that the regular user can open url which must be used only of the user is administrator.

***example* :
localhost:8080/{hostpath}/users** - only admin user must open this url but now i can be opened by admin and regular user.

how to make some of the url restricted for regular user?

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/dom.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/dom.js" />"></script>
<spring:message code="configure.app.path" var="hostpath" />
</head>
<body>
    <article class="mainWrapper">
    <div>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${sessionScope.user.admin}">

                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${active == true}">

                        <h1>ADMIN</h1>
                        <nav class="topNav">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="selected"><a href="${hostpath}/home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="${hostpath}/settings">Settings</a></li>
                                <li><a href="${hostpath}/users">Users</a></li>
                                <li><a href="${hostpath}/groups">Groups</a></li>
                                <li><a href="${hostpath}/pdata">PrivateData</a></li>
                                <li><a href="${hostpath}/secur">Security</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </nav>

                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>

                        <h1>ACTIVATE REGISRATION</h1>
                        <p>some explanation text</p>

                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>

                <br class="clear" />
                <br />

            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>

                <h1>USER</h1>
                <nav class="topNav">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="selected"><a href="${hostpath}/home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="${hostpath}/pdata">PrivateData</a></li>
                        <li><a href="${hostpath}/secur">Security</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </nav>

            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>

    </div>
    </article>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta how to make some of the url restricted for regular user ?

Comment: By implementing security... The fact that you hide something is n't really security. Use Spring Security (as you are using Spring) to apply real security (and also use it to show/hide URLs.

Comment: You are already using Spring so check out Spring Security. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways that you can go about solving your problem.
The way I would do is to get the current loggedin user. Assuming that your have followed the spring security conventions, once you have the current user, you can get that user's role(s) depending on how you have defined in your application and then inject the user in the model, and in your jsp page you can now compare the user role.

this method gets the current loggedin user:

```
  public static User getCurrentUser() {
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        String email = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        loginUser = userService.findUserByEmail(email);
        return new SecurityUser(loginUser);
    }

    return null;
}
```

and then you inject he current user in your model:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getUserPage(Model model) {
     User user = getCurrentUser();
     model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "users";
}
```

Now you can compare the user's role in your jsp:

```
   <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${user.role == 'ADMIN'}">

            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${active == true}">

                    <h1>ADMIN</h1>
                    <nav class="topNav">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="selected"><a href="${hostpath}/home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="${hostpath}/settings">Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="${hostpath}/users">Users</a></li>
                            <li><a href="${hostpath}/groups">Groups</a></li>
                            <li><a href="${hostpath}/pdata">PrivateData</a></li>
                            <li><a href="${hostpath}/secur">Security</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </nav>

                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>

                    <h1>ACTIVATE REGISRATION</h1>
                    <p>some explanation text</p>

                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>

            <br class="clear" />
            <br />

        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
```

If your user can have more than one role, then you have to loop through the roles to check if he has the required role to see the menu.

Well I hope that this can help you, because that is the way I would go around solving it

Comment: The **big** issue with your solution is that is merely prevents the link being rendered in the UI: it does not stop someone manually navigating to /abc/unauthorized_url

Comment: I understood that he wanted to dynamically show the menu to users depending on their roles. now that you mention that he want to block access. you can make changes in the spring security configuration.

Comment: Your solution just hides the links but not restrict them for regular user.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict user access a page using Spring Security, otherwise you can make a Java Filter which will check in the session which role the user have and redirect him to an unauthorized page if he haven't the right to access the page.
It depends on you and the complexity of the app you are developing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Filter, then even if one user share with another some not allowed URL you will be sure he cant access.

A basic example of use would be something like this:

```
public class UsersRestrictionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        logger.debug("URI: {}", request.getRequestURI());
        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        //Here I use spring security from context
        if (isRestrictedURL(request.getRequestURI()) && !user.isAdmin()) {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
            response.sendRedirect(request.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/notAllowedAccess");
        }
        //if the user is allowed to access the url continue flow
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
   }

   private boolean isRestrictedURL(String url){
    //your logic to decide if the URL is only for admin users
   }

   @Override
   public void destroy() {
   }

}
```